# Mongo multi-field filter query and sort - optimization

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongodb-indexes

I have a records collection which has primary_id (unique), secondary_id, status fields among others. The ids are alphanumeric fields (ex. 'ABCD0000') and the status is a numeric (1 - 5).
One of the queries that would be frequently used is to filter by id (equality or range) and status.

examples:

1. records where primary_id between 'ABCD0000' - 'ABCN0000' and status is 2 or 3, sort by primary_id.
2. records where secondary_id between 'ABCD0000' - 'ABCD0000' and status is 2 or 3, sort by primary_id (or secondary_id if that would help).

The status in the filter will mostly be (status in (2,3)).

Initially we had an single index on each of the fields. But the query times out when the range is large. I have tried adding multiple indexes (single & compound) and with different ways to write the filter but couldn't get a decent performance. Now I have those indexes:

```
[
{primary_id: 1},
{secondary_id: 1},
{status: 1},
{primary_id: 1, status: 1},
{status: 1, primary_id: 1},
{status: 1, secondary_id: 1}
]
```

This query (with or without sort on primary_id)

```
{ $and: [ 
{ primary_id: { $gte: 'ABCD0000' } }, 
{ primary_id: { $lte: 'ABCN0000' } }, 
{status: { $in: [2,3] } } 
] }
```

use the following plan:

```
...
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "filter" : {
            "status" : {
                    "$in" : [
                            2,
                            3
                    ]
            }
    },
    "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                    "primary_id" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "primary_idx",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "primary_id" : [ ]
            },
            "isUnique" : true,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                    "primary_id" : [
                            "[\"ABCD0000\", \"ABCN0000\"]"
                    ]
            }
    }
},
```

So, It seems that the FETCH step takes long time if the number of returned rows is large. Surprisingly, while running initial tests the status, primary_id compound index was sometimes picked as the winning plan and that was super-fast (few seconds). But for some reason its not been picked by Mongo anymore. I guess when the query needs to sort by primary_id this compound index wont be picked, as i understood from the Mongo docs

> If the query does not specify an equality condition on an index prefix that precedes or overlaps with the sort specification, the operation will not efficiently use the index.

I tried to change the query as below but that is still not optimized

```
{$or: [
{ $and: [ { primary_id: { $gte: 'ABCD0000' } }, { primary_id: { $lte: 'ABCN0000' } }, { status: 2 } ]},
{ $and: [ { primary_id: { $gte: 'ABCD0000' } }, { primary_id: { $lte: 'ABCN0000' } }, { status: 3 } ]}
]}
```

Any suggestions on what would be a better indexing or query strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with 2 indexes

primary_id, status and secondary_id, status.

If timeout is still occurring, can you increase the query time out value? - considering the large data-set that you are trying to read from.

If those indexes don't help and good response time is expected , then you should look at hardware constraints - is your hardware good enough (read mongodb's working set size). Either scale up the server/hardware or look at sharding if performance is really a concern and your data size is going to grow.

OR - store status 2 and 3 in separate collections to reduce the "working set size" while querying for those.